# Why the localization $D_P$ of a Dedekind domain $D$ at the prime ideal $P$ is a principal ideal domain?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, localization, dedekind-domain

Let $D$ be a Dedekind domain and let $P$ be a non-zero prime ideal in $D$.

Why the localization $D_P$ at the prime ideal $P$ is a principal ideal domain?

Would you help me please?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does prime factorization look like in $D_P$?

Comment: Could you define Dedekind domain? I've seen some definitions where this is part of the definition.

Comment: I am working with the book "Basic Algebra 2" .DEFINITION. A domian $D$ is called a Dedekind domain if every $D$-fractional ideal of $F$ (the field of fractions of $D$) is invertible.

Comment: Which definition of "Dedekind domain" are you starting from? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_domain#Alternative_definitions) Ultimately, your claim follows from the fact that $D_P$ is a discrete valuation ring for every non-zero prime $P$.

Comment: @Hurkyl I think that a prime ideal in $D_P$ is of the form $Q_P$ such that $Q$ is a prime ideal of $D$ contained in $P$.

Comment: @User1999: That is true. Now simplify what you just said using what you know about the prime ideals of $D$.

Comment: @Ravi 10 I am working with the book "Basic Algebra 2". DEFINITION. A domain $D$ is called a Dedekind domain if every $D$-fractional ideal of $F$ (the field of fractions of $D$) is invertible.

Comment: @Kenny Wong I am referring to the definition DD3 that every non-zero fractional ideal of $R$ is invertible.

Comment: Okay, then if you can get from definition DD3 to definitions DD4 and DD2, then you know that all non-zero prime ideals are maximal, and localizations at all maximal ideals are dvrs, hence are principal.

Comment: @Kenny Wong Thank you for your answer. I am clear why if $D$ is Dedekind domain, then every non-zero prime ideal is maximal. I cannot prove that localizations at all maximal ideals are unique factorization domains.:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ is a Dedekind domain, so is any localisation at a prime ideal $D_
{\mathfrak p}$. Now an invertible ideal is a projective module, so $\mathfrak pD_
{\mathfrak p}$ is projective. Now, on a local ring, finitely generated projective modules are free, so so $\mathfrak pD_{\mathfrak p}$ is a free ideal, and free ideals are principal.